# What does this error mean: “maverick is not supported.” when installing AppScale?

Tags: kubuntu

I am trying to install AppScale on a cluster, and I'm running this command:

```
debian/appscale_build.sh
```

when I get this error:

```
maverick is not supported
```

what does this mean? I am unable to understand it.

This is my ubuntu details:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.10  
Release:    10.10
Codename:   maverick
```

Comment: Also, Maverick is End of Life, so if you're still using 10.10 you need to upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AppScale image only support Lucid right now. See http://code.google.com/p/appscale/wiki/ImageCreationLucid 
on how to create an image.

For additional help email the mailing list at:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/appscale_community

-Raj

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking at this: https://launchpad.net/appscale?  A quick google of "installing app scale on ubuntu" provides me w/ this page:http://code.google.com/p/appscale/wiki/Getting_Started_Current_Release but doesn't show a current release outside of Karmic and the last build of anything from 2011.  I would assume this means there are no current packages for Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick) which is why it isn't installing and not supported.

I hope this helps out with your question.

JOnathan

Answer (score 2):

Docs have moved to
http://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki

Along with a easier script to start a build:

```
wget -O - http://bootstrap.appscale.com | sh
```